# How to run a symfony project well on my localhost

Tags: symfony1, localhost, symfony-1.4

1. I have just downloaded a symfony web project from git to my windows 7 machine. I set it up in my c://xampp/htdocs/projectx
2. On my C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts I added the line:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 projectx.old
   ```
3. On my httpd.conf file i added:

   ```
   <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
     ServerName projectx.old
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/projectx/web"
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/projectx/web">
       AllowOverride All
       Allow from All
     </Directory>

     Alias /sf C:/xampp/htdocs/projectx/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/projectx/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
       AllowOverride All
       Allow from All
     </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

But when I access the project on my browser as projectx.old, it doesnt load the css. The stylesheet links return the error: Object not found! And they have their links pointed as

```
  projectx.old/uploads/asset-cache/97e8cd51a4572cfb747026ce55e7e074.css
```

Help me solve this problem.

Comment: The project seems to be using some caching mechanism for asset files. You would have to find out how to dump the css to the `uploads/asset-cache` folder. Look through the plugins of your project and the tasks in `lib\task`, maybe you'll find anything interesting there.

Comment: Why set your css in the uploads folder? The css is exists? Check the gitignore file, there is the uploads folder or not.

Comment: Sorry for late reply guys. @turbod I didnt develop the project. Actually I am new to symfony. I didnt find any files under the uploads folder. I downloaded the project via svn so I dont think there is a gitignore file.

Comment: @TechyTimo in the original project where is the css? If accessible the original page in the internet. I think you must download the upload folder too. Is the uploads folder under [svn ignore](http://superuser.com/questions/142109/finding-all-directories-in-a-repository-with-svn-property-svn-ignore)?

Comment: @turbod the original page is actually bookcheetah.com. If you inspect you also find the css to be in the same directory web/uploads/asset-cache. The directory web/uploads/asset-cache doesnt exist in my case. All my css is in web/css folder. There is no css in the .svn hidden folder

Comment: There certainly is a process for deploying your css. Is it a css? Or are there .less/.sass files? For the sake of getting your project running and checking on things you could simply change the url in the template and check then what processes are running. Maybe there is a "deploy" option in the sites' backend.

Comment: there are a bunch of css and less files.

Answer (score 1):

I think your _uploads folder doesn't exists, so you must download it by ftp, or you can try

```
php symfony plugin:publish-assets
```

this command.

Comment: Thank you. Where is the "_uploads" folder supposed to be located? I have web/uploads/ and web/uploads/media_items directories. I ran the command, streamed a lot of warnings then I ran the project again but the css files are still not found.